# Tableau - Most recent record by multiple criteria

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a dashboard in tableau and need to pull the most recent record for each CustomerID ONLY IF the shipment type is 1, 2, or 3 (exclude 4) AND the customer is set to a type of a, c, d (exclude b).

Here's a sample of the data structure:
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjNj1.png)
Here is what the answer should be:
[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5YAg.png)

New to tableau desktop and have been playing around for way too long - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If a customer A’s most recent shipment is of type 4, and her previous shipment is of type 3, do you want to see that type 3 record? Or do you want no record for customer A?

Comment: I would want no record in that case. Trying to show only records where all criteria are met. Thanks for clarifying @AlexBlakemore

Comment: Do you have a Shipment ID column?- say a surrogate key, hopefully unique and always increasing over time. That's not required, but allows a simpler solution if you have that. If not, you have a nitpick question about how to handle two most recent shipments with the same timestamp.

Comment: I'll type up an answer when I get a chance, but in the meantime, read about Level of Detail (LOD) calculations in the online help. That's the critical Tableau feature useful for solving this type of problem. (you could also use table calcs, but LOD calcs are probably a better choice for this one)

Comment: I don't have a shipmentID unfortunately. For this data set i dont think it would be possible to get 2 shipments for the same customer with the same timestamp. Thank you so much! I'll take a look at LOD calcs

Comment: OK, see the example I posted. Just change the LOD calc that calculates the max shipment id per customer, to calculated the max shipment DATE per customer, and adjust the boolean calculation that uses that max id, to instead check the max date

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using LOD calculations and filters [Example workbook](https://public.tableau.com/shared/3NKK89PTF?:display_count=yes)
You can download the workbook to see the calculations and filters.

It assumes each shipment row has a unique Shipment Id that increases with date, so that it can be used to determine which shipment is the latest per customer.

See the filters and calculated fields that support them. The solution uses a context filter to make one filter apply prior to the others, and an LOD calculation to find the id of the latest shipment for each customer.

```
{ FIXED [Customer] : max([Shipment ID]) }
```